# Why there is undefined behavior of extern shared memory in CUDA?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, cuda

I am trying to learn about dynamic allocation of shared memory in CUDA. I have written one simple program which returns error using cudaGetLastError. I have allocated shared memory of size 100 integer elements while launching the kernel. I tried to access 101-127 indexed memory memory elements and it don't show any error, but while access 130th element it is giving error "unspecified launch failure". I my opinion it should give this error while access 101 element also because I have allocated size for only 100 element.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
__global__ void xyz(int offset)
{
 extern __shared__ int array[];
 array[101]=offset; 
 printf("%d\n", array[101]);
}

int main()
{
 dim3 grid(1,1,1);
 dim3 block(100,1,1);
 int offset=50;
 xyz<<<grid,block,sizeof(int)*100>>>(offset);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 cudaError_t err=cudaGetLastError();
 if(err!=cudaSuccess)
 {
    printf("Error is =%s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: So your question can be summarized as "why is undefined behaviour undefined in a particular way"? It probably has to do with allocation granularity and the design of the hardware, but why to you care?

Comment: Yes I think cudagetlasterror should give error in this case

Comment: What happens when you run your test code with `cuda-memcheck` in each case?

Comment: There is no error even after running with "cuda-memcheck"

Comment: @RobertCrovella I run same code on Titan Black with compute capability 3.5 and it is giving error with "cuda-memcheck" otherwise not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I don't think accessing beyond the end of an array on the host (in ordinary C/C++ code) will immediately trigger a fault (e.g. seg fault, etc.)

On the GPU, there is no hardware mechanism that tracks all allocations down to the byte level.  There is a general hardware mechanism that can track allocated pages of memory, and discover if an access is outside of a valid page, but the granularity is not down to the byte or element level (and I don't think it is that way on the host CPU either).

Architecturally, newer GPUs have better hw access tracking mechanisms.  Also, cuda-memcheck can do tighter tracking of accesses, at the expense of considerable performance reduction, because it is doing partly SW based tracking and partly HW based tracking, perhaps somewhat analogous to a tool like valgrind on the host.

So although you seem to have an expectation that any deviation from allocated space will immediately trigger a fault, the GPU HW itself does not support that (and AFAIK CPU HW does not either, at least in modern demand-paged virtual memory OS's).   With software intervention (i.e. cuda-memcheck) the situation is improved generally, but will still vary depending on HW generation.